# How should smartphone apps be cited as sources?

Tags: discussion, citations

Two questions were posted that used a link to the Google Play store and a screenshot of the app as their citation. The same user also posted to the Chemistry Stack Exchange site with the same method.

What is the proper way to provide a citation if a smartphone app is used as a source?

Comment: Which questions were those?

Comment: It appears that the answers have been removed as spam because the app was written by the author of the answer without disclosing that fact.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**
Smartphone apps shouldn't be used, or cited to build a proper answer or question.

**Background**
Smart phone apps shouldn't be cited on scientific stacks. Even if they are knowledge databases of some kind, we need more proper sources than that. Personally I dislike even wikipedia as a source for the premise of an answer (or question), as the content is volatile, subject to change, stacked with circle referencing (A can be explained by B - link to B says that B can be explained by A) and indeed often outright incorrect. It's fine to use it as a link to highlight a term and use it for background purposes, but to use wilkipedia as a source to build your answer on, I would say ***no***. Likewise, smartphone apps can be build by anyone, and stuffed with nonsense matter, which is not regulated, controlled, or reviewed in any way.

Comment: Additionally one you could argue that the app is not the source. If you do this, you could also add Firefox or Chrome as a "source".

Comment: @Chris Good point :)

Answer (score -1):

The site's own FAQ on How to [reference material written by others](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) says:

> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

One possible standard to use in this case would be the American Phsycological Association's (APA) Style Blog which has an posting "[How to Cite a Mobile App](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/03/how-to-cite-a-mobile-app.html)" by Chelsea Lee.

The style they use is:

> Rightsholder, A. A. (year). Title of Software or Program (Version number) [Mobile application software]. Retrieved from `http://xxxxx`

This question has also been asked and answered on the Academic Stack Exchange site as "[How to cite a Google Play app?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48827/how-to-cite-a-google-play-app)". The answer there cites the APA Style Blog as well.

Comment: +1 I think this is a valid response to the question asked. If an app provided a user the means to ask/answer a question, it's not harmful to include a citation (though this is certainly not preferred -- see @Chris's [comment](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/how-should-smartphone-apps-be-cited-as-sources#comment5433_3854) to AliceD's post). Regardless of whether the app itself is cited, *much more important* (as AliceD's post suggests) is that the user cites the underlying info source the App user used to generate his/her app. This is more work, but the correct approach